# Reading values from webpage programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, android-activity, web-crawler, html

I don't know what it called, but i think this is possible

I am looking to write something(don't know the exact name) that will,
go to a webpage and select a value from  drop-down box on that page and read values from that page after selection, I am not sure weather it called crawler or activity, i am new to this but i heard long time back from one of my friend this can be done,

can any one please give me a head start

Thanks

Comment: Is the webpage arbitrary, or is it a specific webpage?

Answer (score 3):

You need an [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) client library (perhaps [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) in C, or some C# wrapper for it, or some native C# HTTP client library like [this](https://code.google.com/p/c-sharp-http-client/)).

You also need to parse the retrieved [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) content. So you probably need an [HTML parsing library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers) (maybe [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)).

<sup>If the targeted webpage is nearly fixed and has e.g. some comments to ease finding the relevant part, you might use simpler or ad-hoc parsing techniques.</sup>

Some sites might send a nearly empty static HTML client, with the actual page being dynamically constructed by Javascript scripts ([Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)). In that case, you are unlucky.

Maybe you want some [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) ....

Answer (score 1):

One simple way (but not the most efficient way) is to simply read the webpage as `String` using the `WebClient`, for example:

```
WebClient Web = new WebClient();
String Data = Web.DownloadString("Address");
```

Now since HTML is simply an XML document you can parse the string to a `XDocument` and look up the tag that represents the dropdown box. Parsing the string to XDocument is done this way:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Pase(Data);
```

Update:

If you want to read the result of the selected value, and that result is displayed within the page do this:

Get all the items as I explained. 
If the page does not make use of models, then you can use your selected value as an argument for example :

```
www.somepage.com/Name=YourItem?
```

Read the page again and find the value

Comment: I need to select a value from a drop-down box on that web page and then read the values

Comment: Well, in that case, there's multiple scenarios, one is the selected value results in a new page being opened where your value is gonna be shown, that is possible by my answer, you need to generate the address according to the selected Item and download the page again. But if your value is displayed somewhere in the page like for example a textfield, that wouldn't be statically possible using this approach.

Comment: <http://www.vectonemobile.co.uk/pay-as-you-go/vm-rates/standard/international-rates.aspx> on this page when i change the values on the drop down box URL not changing, may be some kind of dynamic/ajax ?

Comment: @Srikanth: If the dropdowns are "Pay As You Go ", "Pay Monthly", etc, the problem is then way too easy just get the link for example the free sim link is stored in this tag : <a href="/pay-as-you-go/free-sim.aspx" title="Free SIM"> Free SIM</a>, look up the href value after you find your element using the XDocument.

Comment: http://www.vectonemobile.co.uk/pay-as-you-go/vm-rates/standard/international-rates.aspx

Comment: I am not sure weather you are able to see the full page or not, i need to rates the international call rates for each and country from that website

Comment: @Srikanth: I thinks the rates are fetched from the database or calculated in the server side (Code Behind as this is classical ASP.NET), you do not have access to the server side, I checked the whole HTML, this is not done using JS. The page is then updated using by updating a div tag inside of it, like for example by .InnetHTML or something similar